# Flex - toggle bold text in TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, text, bold

I am making a RTE in Flex and am trying to make text formatting buttons.

```
<s:ToggleButton id="boldBtn" width="50" height="50" label="B" click="boldBtn_clickHandler(event)" color="#000000" fontWeight="bold"/>
```

and my code

```
protected function boldBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var txtLayFmt:TextLayoutFormat = mainTextField.getFormatOfRange(null,
                mainTextField.selectionAnchorPosition,
                mainTextField.selectionActivePosition);
            txtLayFmt.fontWeight = (txtLayFmt.fontWeight == FontWeight.BOLD) ? FontWeight.NORMAL : FontWeight.BOLD; **// Causing the NULL Pointer exception**
            mainTextField.setFormatOfRange(txtLayFmt,
                mainTextField.selectionAnchorPosition,
                mainTextField.selectionActivePosition);
            mainTextField.setFocus();
        }
```

When I type some text into the TextArea, and select it then click the boldBtn I get a Cannot access a property or methof of a null object reference. If I comment out txtLayFmt.fontWeight = (txtLayFmt.fontWeight == FontWeight.BOLD) ? FontWeight.NORMAL : FontWeight.BOLD; the program doesn't crash so this seems to be the offending line but I don't see why.

**EDIT**
I'm now trying this code. It works when I ut it in a Desktop application, but when I put it in a mobile project it doesn't work. Any ideas?

......

```
private function btnBold_click(evt:MouseEvent):void {
trace("Clicked"); // Traces to output ok
var styleObj:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
styleObj.fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD;
mainTextField.setFormatOfRange(styleObj);
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You're getting a null error.  Doesn't particularly crash, but it means there's something wrong with your code.  In all probability, the getFormatOfRange is returning null.

Comment: I just made an edit, this code looks fine but isn't working

Comment: What do you mean by "looks fine" and "isn't working"?  Looks like there's no null checks in there.  Also, what's mainTextField?  Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: I think I discovered the problem. Mobile apps don't handle TLF, that's why the code works as a desktop app but not a mobile app. Is there a wayto accomplish this without using TextLayoutFormat?

Comment: Erm, I'm fairly sure mobile apps *does* handle TLF because I've used it myself.

Comment: Do you have to do something special to use them?

Comment: TLF in a mobile application

In general, avoid text controls that use Text Layout Framework (TLF) in mobile applications. The mobile skins of the TextArea and TextInput controls are optimized for mobile applications and do not use TLF as their desktop counterparts do. TLF is used in desktop applications for providing a rich set of controls over text rendering., from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c6a9f451212b87fe7e87-7fff.html

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css and it will use TLF and support all the normal functionality.

```
s|TextArea
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.TextAreaSkin");
}
```